# Objective-C loop within loop and ARC memory issues with @autoreleasepool

Tags: objective-c, out-of-memory, automatic-ref-counting

I have a situation where I have to use for loop within another for loop.

When the number of iterations is not to big (<10000) it works correctly, and after the process completes, memory is cleared properly and app is working fine.

But for sometimes the number of iterations can be very large. The internal loop always have some finite amount (20 in my case) but the outer loop vary from very small to very large (can go up to 100000).

Something similar to this will cause an insufficient memory error and the app will be terminated:

```
    @autoreleasepool {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i=0; i<1000000;i++){
        @autoreleasepool {
            NSString *dataString = dataArray[i];
            NSArray *temp = [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

            NSString *string1 = @"";
            NSString *string2 = @"";
            NSString *string3 = @"";

            for(int j=0; j<20; j++){
                NSString *tag = temp[j];
                NSArray *kv = [tag componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
                switch ([kv[0] intValue]) {
                    case 0:
                        string1 = kv[1];
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        string2 = kv[1];
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        string3 = kv[1];
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            NSString *final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", string1, string2, string3];
            [array addObject:final];

        }
    }
    [self process:array];
    // process array
}
```

`@autoreleasepool` doesn't seems to be working at all (almost the same amount of memory is be use with and without @autoreleasepool blocks)

I tried removing the inner loop (just for testing) and the code works correctly and memory is released after each iteration. But when using the inner loop, memory doesn't get released and eventually app is terminated with an insufficient memory error.

Can anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong here, I cannot find a solution for this.

**EDITED**

oh stupid me :)

I found the issue, it has nothing to do with loops or any thing.
One of the switch case has a date string, I need that string to convert to another date format

```
    NSDateFormatter *dFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dFormatter setDateFormat:fromFormat];
    NSDate *date = [dFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [dFormatter setDateFormat:toFormat];
    NSString *newDateString = [dFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return newDateString;
```

so every outer loop this code will run once and this is the code that make my memory keep filling until it crashes.

So I stops creating new NSDateFormatter every time and made two formatters as global formatters. So now my code works smoothly :)

```
    [self.formatter setDateFormat:fFormat];
    NSDate *date = [self.formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [self.dOnlyFormatter setDateFormat:tFormat];
    NSString *newDateString = [self.dOnlyFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return newDateString;
```

But what I don't understand is why these NSDateFormatter objects doesn't get dealloc after method finished.

Comment: is the code example the actual code that produces the problem or is this a simplified version?

Comment: its a simplified version - but the actual code has similar loops - first loop process an array of strings and second loop will loop the array obtained by tokenizing of the strings inside first array, and final string wil be added to a global array - but this global array doesnt seems causing any issues - i will append real code to the question

Comment: does the non-simplified version add anything to the array thats on the outside there?

Comment: you should post the real loop, I guess as Fonix that there happens something that does create reference from "inside to outside" and thus the autoreleasepool won't be effective

Comment: yep, your updated code shows that you add to an array outside of the autorelease pool, therefore you are simply just storing too many objects to fit into memory, so you will need to optimize your memory footprint somehow

Comment: I will try to remove outside array but I have a related question - let say we remove that outside array - just loop withing loop running(just testing) - it still filling up memory - no outside code involved

Comment: I don't get why the test loop allocates anything (on the heap).. those are constant strings .. can somebody enlighten me here?

Comment: In response to your edit: The testLoop method allocates three strings on the heap on each iteration. New instances of ` @"x"` etc. are created on each iteration and released shortly after. The key difference ot my answer is that I pre-declared the `NSString` for `string1` to `3 (that may not make much of a difference at all) and predeclared `@"x"` etc als constants. The `*const` makes all the difference.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *final;
NSString *string1;
NSString *string2;
NSString *string3;
NSString *const empty = @"";
NSString *const x = @"x";
NSString *const y = @"y";
NSString *const z = @"z";

for(int i=0; i<100000;i++){

        string1 = empty;
        string2 = empty;
        string3 = empty;

        for(int j=0; j<20; j++){ // if we remove this loop this works perfectly
            switch (j) {
                case 0:
                    string1 = x;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    string2 = y;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    string3 = z;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", string1, string2, string3];

}
```

As a positive side effect it could be even faster.

Comment: actually when I remove NSString *string1 = @""; from loop and add it before loop it started to use very less memory than before but still original issue didnt solved,  but now its processing lot more iterations before the error, i will work on this to if there any solution

Comment: You could try adding the autoreleasepool again, because you are still frequently allocating new memory for new strings. That is what all NSString methods starting with "string" or "copy" actually do.  (You can even have the @autoreleasepool within the second loop in your original code. That would solve the memory allocation issue using my code actually avoids unnessessary allocations)

Comment: BTW, does it run faster?

Comment: What's the point? `final` will be clogging outer autorelease pool, and in your case array is not used. I can suggest to remove this code as it does not do anything as a side effect you get even more speed.